# A TabBar with 6 tabs, A ViewController, A WebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm begginer for swift.
I want to create the web view application optimized navigation (to see commerce site).

I decide to use `TabBarController`(with 6 tabs) and `UIWebView`. And I could implement this application.

1. `TabBarController` related to 6 `ViewControllers`
2. 6 `ViewControllers` has each `UIWebView`(specified URI)

I could see 6 tabs like website.
But I have question...

- This way is NOT efficient.(6 `ViewController` have each `UIWebView`)
- Can each `UIWebView` generated in diffrent timing have same session?(must have same session)

If possible, I want to use a `TabBarController` with 6 tab and a `ViewController` and a `UIWebView`.
And when I could select a tab(in 6tabs), I want to change the url of the same `UIWebView`.

Please tell me how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Custom class of each view related to same ViewController.swift in storyboard. I delete UIWebView from storyboard and I rewrite ViewControllers.swift and add UIWebView from code. And because I can tell selected tab by "self.tabBarController!.selectedIndex", switch URL and load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it is not possible to have one `ViewController` in `TabBarController`, but you can have one `WebView` and share it between your view controllers.

1. Create WebView in singleton style:

   ```
   class WebView: UIWebView
   {
       static let sharedInstance = WebView()
   }
   ```
2. Place it on view, that will appear on screen:

   ```
   class FirstViewController: UIViewController
   {
       override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
       {
           view.addSubview(WebView.sharedInstance)
           WebView.sharedInstance.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)

          // configure it as you need: load request, setup autolayout constraints, etc..
       }
   }

   class SecondViewController: UIViewController
   {   
       override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
       {
           view.addSubview(WebView.sharedInstance)
           WebView.sharedInstance.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)

           // same
       }
   }

   // and same in each view controller
   ```

Comment: thank you! I'm clear! your answer is close to what I thought to want to do.